# Remove 0-9 Buttons of Soft Keyboard?

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard

How to remove these 0-9 buttons from soft keyboard appeared from EditText?

I can't find any InputType that can help me from this [docs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e5Nq3.jpg)

Tried to use this but the buttons still appear.

```
android:inputType="text"
android:digits="a,b,c"
```

[image]

Comment: there is no way I think. Only thing you can do is to remove the numbers exactly after they are inputted.

Comment: did you try this `android:digits="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"` without comma separated?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the IME options. Check below link

https://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/style.html